Help drafting a question about correct phrasing and grammar regarding English to Latin translation of a slogan or meaningful sentence
Oxford House is a company that has recovery houses for alcoholics and addicts all over the nation. I live in an Oxford House and I'm doing some fundraising for our group by selling T-shirts. A design I'm thinking might be scroll work that would have something like, "I might be slow, but I never go backwards." Or, "Having fallen, I have arisen." Or maybe something similar or different I don't know? Go nuts with it, give me something cool I challenge you, haha, kidding, any help would be great. Thank you kindly. James.

Welcome! This sounds like an interesting topic for a motto. But the site is meant for very specific questions, where there is only one question, and where answers can be more or less objectively rated. Requests for creativity fall outside the scope of the site, alas. You could pick one possible motto and ask about that. There is an additional rule for translation requests, however: the asker must explain what he has tried to translate the phrase to Latin, and give as much context and nuance as possible about the phrase. Sorry about all the rules, we had issues with translations in the past.

Could also ask for a classical phrase that fits this best.

Yes, I agree with both comments I'm wondering if I have to go back and rephrase?
